# Linkage in Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I get "ValueError: Linkage matrix 'Z' must have 4 columns."

```
X = data.drop(['grain_variety'], axis=1)
y = data['grain_variety']
mergings = linkage(X, method='complete')
dendrogram(X,
           labels=y,
           leaf_rotation=90,
           leaf_font_size=6)
plt.show()
```

I do not understand my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it normal to not use your linkage matrix: ***mergings***, in the dendogram function?

Comment: You are right. I have done that. I get another error.  KeyError: -121

Comment: A KeyError generally means the key doesn't exist. Handle the KeyError in your code to see which key doesn't exist.